# Ruby/JRuby Conflict - Invalid switch in RUBYOPT -F {RuntimeError}

Tags: ruby, jruby, conflict

I have an installer made with NSIS that at a certain point runs the following 3 commands:

```
...
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\Application"
nsExec::ExecToLog "jruby -S bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production"
nsExec::ExecToLog "jruby -S bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production"
nsExec::ExecToLog "jruby -S bundle exec rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=production"  
...
```

The installer packs JRuby with all the necessary gems already installed and it adds JRuby to Path enviroment variable before executing any `jruby` command.

**The problem appears when I try to run my installer on a machine that has Ruby installed: when the installer gets to execute the above commands, it fails, returning some error like: `C:\Ruby192\bin\ruby.exe invalid switch in RUBYOPT -F (RuntimeError)`**

I have checked the Path environment variable, and it looks pretty much like this:

```
C:\Ruby192\bin; ... ;C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApplication\JRuby\jruby-1.6.3\bin
```

My guess is that there is some kind of conflict between Ruby and JRuby. But I cannot figure out how to solve the problem.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using RVM: http://beginrescueend.com/.  Then you have have both ruby and jruby running without conflicting each other.